# How to populate rails 2 select using helpers and conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, select

I'm working with a simple select like this:

<%=  select(@file, @file.file_id, File.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>

However, I would like to add some conditions to that "all"...

for example

"id != @file.id"

(I don't want the current file to be shown in the select list).

how can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
File.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", @file.id]).map {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}
```